# Understanding Logging Priority & Options in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

From my understanding once we switch on database logging, the entire DB goes into logging mode and generates redo logs.

I want to categorically exclude/include some tables/tablespaces from this logging as they are not required for recovery incase of failures.

Is there any priority on the logging options and to exclude certain tables/tablespaces from logging so as to reduce some of the traffic going to redo logs.

Answer (score 3):

The database generates redo even without archivelog mode, I guess you meant enabling archivelog mode by logging.

What you asked for is not possible.

Conventional path DML will generate redo, it can not be turned on/off per tablespace.

Direct path loads (INSERT /*+ APPEND */, INSERT /*+ APPEND_VALUES */, CTAS, Data Pump import) and maintenance operations (like table move, index build) can bypass logging, but that is not your everyday workload.

You can exclude tablespaces from the backup, but you can not exclude them from redo.